# What is the difference between 前と and 前に?

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-と

I've seen both used to mean "X ago", e.g. "六日前と" and "3ヶ月前に".

Comment: In what context did you see 六日前**と** ?

Comment: This question makes no sense in its current form. Particle depends on the predicate which you didn't include. Either one can be correct.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between 前と and 前に?
>   I've seen both used to been "X ago", e.g. "六日前と" and "3ヶ月前に".

Those you've seen must be both correct, but に is the one to say 'X ago'.

と is used for a different reason such as 六日前と三か月前に, or 六日前と言っていました.

**に** indicates the location of something including **time** or owner of things or ideas or values or etc.
**と** **connects** nouns or noun-like words, or is used to describe something by *indicating the **content** of a quotation or thought or idea,* and the form of the content doesn't matter whether it's a word or phrase or clause; 六日前**と**いう話, 六日前の話**と**いうことです, 「六日前に彼と会った」と言いました, etc.

Comment: I would bet the most common と after ○○前 would be a part of と比べて or と変わらない, not the one you suggest.

Comment: と is much more often used as と言った, or と思った, or という than ○○前と比べて or ○○前と変わらない. The point I tried to tell the OP; 名詞＋と is followed by a verb. Interestingly when it's 思う, we seem to prefer 動詞＋と思う; ex. すると思う, だと思う.

Answer (score 0):

Case examples I guess are as follows.

> -（Ａ）彼｛かれ｝が私｛わたし｝を訪｛たず｝ねて来｛き｝たのは**六日前と**思｛おも｝う。 *I think it was six days ago when he visited me*.
>   -（Ｂ）彼は**六日前に**私を訪ねて来た。 *He visited me six days ago*.

(A) makes sense, but it'll become better if you edit it as 彼が私を訪ねて来たのは六日前**だ**と思う。or 彼が私を訪ねて来たのは六日前**である**と思う。
More precisely, it is 彼が私を訪ねて来た **日｛ひ｝** は、六日前であると思う。

**と** in this phrase is a particle used for quoting (with speech, thoughts, etc.); quoting particle​. With this particle 六日前 becomes the quoted object of the verb 思う.

On the other hand, phrase (B) is a very common usage of に, which is a particle indicating time.